# Skew only one corner of a div

Tags: css, skew

I need to pull only the bottom right corner of the hero div down. I have tried all configurations of skews and rotate.
[image]

https://codepen.io/alecfried/full/pmvLMw

```html
<div class="position-relative" style="min-height: 400px; background: purple; width: 100%;transform-origin: bottom; transform: skewX(-17deg); overflow: hidden;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution (after your comment). Though I have not removed, this `<div class=" wrapper ">` has no duty here.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* may remove width:100%, as div is always 100% */
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.position-relative {
  min-height: 400px;
  background: purple;
  width: 100%;
  /* may remove width:100%, as div is always 100% */
  /* transform-origin: bottom; */
  /* transform: skewX(-17deg); */
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="position-relative"> </div>
</div>
```

About clip-path you can have some visual example at [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is achievable but you may need to apply this type of trick! :)

```css
.wraper {
        width: 100%; /* may remove width:100%, as div is always 100% */
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .position-relative {
        min-height: 400px;
        background: purple;
        width: 100%; /* may remove width:100%, as div is always 100% */
        transform-origin: bottom;
        transform: skewX(-17deg);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="position-relative"> </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need the bottom right corner to droop down like in the image.